# Hive - How to load data from a file with filename as a column?

Tags: hadoop, load, hive, filenames

I am running the following commands to create my table ABC and insert data from all files that are in my designated file path.  Now I want to add a column with filename, but I can't find any way to do that without looping through the files or something.  Any suggestions on what the best way to do this would be?

```
CREATE TABLE ABC
(NAME string
,DATE string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE;

hive -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '${DATA_FILE_PATH}' INTO TABLE ABC;"
```

Comment: Just thought of another option - use sed or awk to add the filename to the file before doing the load?

Comment: I gave up on the load, and I'm just using awk to add filename to the end of each line:

    awk 'BEGIN{ OFS="\t" }{ print $0,FILENAME }

Answer (score 1):

Hive does have [virtual columns](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VirtualColumns), which include `INPUT__FILE__NAME`. The link shows how to use this in a statement.

To fill another table with the filename as a column. Assuming your location of your data is hdfs://hdfs.location:port/data/folder/filename1

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ABC2;
CREATE TABLE ABC2 (
    filename STRING COMMENT 'this is the file the row was in',
    name STRING,
    date STRING);
INSERT INTO TABLE ABC2 SELECT split(INPUT__FILE__NAME,'folder/')[1],* FROM ABC;
```

You can alter the split to change how much of the full path you actually want to store.